# How to save header in NODE.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm

I am new to NODE.JS 
Can anyone help me? When I run the following command:

```
npm install --save express-handlebars
```

It gives following error:

```
+ express-handlebars@3.1.0
updated 1 package and audited 185 packages in 3.51s
found 4 vulnerabilities (1 moderate, 3 high)
run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

instead of saving the header file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What header file?  That's not an error, it looks like the package installed properly.  What specifically is the problem?

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by header but there is no such thing with npm. You just downloaded a package that got installed and npm displays a message because it found vulnerabilities in this package

Answer (score -1):

it should work. make sure that you have everything updated.